# Remove all whitespaces in string

Tags: sql, oracle, removing-whitespace

I have to remove all whitespaces in String `'5 000 000,5' to '5000000,5'`.

I tried 3 below but it did not work

```
select replace('5 000 000,5',' ','') from dual; 
select regexp_replace('5 000 000,5', '[[:space:]]*','') from dual;
select regexp_replace('5 000 000,5', ' ','') from dual;
```

Or anyone know how to convert this String '5 000 000,5' to number because TO_NUMBER failed.
Thanks

Comment: What is the result of: select replace('5 000 000,5',' ','') from dual;

Comment: You just need to tweak your queries a bit to get the correct output. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Using **`REGEXP_REPLACE` and `SPACE` class**.

`Select regexp_replace('your_value', '[[:space:]]+', '') from dual:`

2. Using **`REPLACE`**

`Select REPLACE('your_value', chr(32), '') from dual:`

Comment: I think you have typo error.  You have `'chr(32)'`.  You did not mean `'chr(32)'`, just `chr(32)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this and remove any non-numeric chars like comma (`,`)

```
SELECT  to_number(regexp_replace('5 000 000,5', '[^0-9]', '')) FROM    dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the proplem is your NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS, that should work

```
select to_number('5 000 000,5', '9G999G999D0', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '', ''')
from dual
```